Can \AddToHookWithArguments let us access to the arguments of a command that has an optional argument?
The following MCE:
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {Foo}
  \seq_show:N \g_tmpa_seq
}
\AddToHookWithArguments{cmd/textbf/before}{
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_show:N \g_tmpa_seq
}
% \AddToHookWithArguments{cmd/section/before}{
%   \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {#1}
%   \seq_show:N \g_tmpa_seq
% }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\textbf{Bold face}
\end{document}

points out that:

we can add to hook (without argument: \AddToHook) for commands with optional argument (here \section),
we can add to hook (with argument: \AddToHookWithArguments) for commands without optional argument (here \textbf),
we can't add to hook (with argument: \AddToHookWithArguments) for commands with optional argument (here \section; the same would arise with the \item command.)

Indeed, if the commented lines:
\AddToHookWithArguments{cmd/section/before}{
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_show:N \g_tmpa_seq
}

are uncommented, we get with the error:

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \__hook_toplevel cmd/section/before

Hence my question: Can \AddToHookWithArguments let us access to the arguments of a command that has an optional argument?

\section has no arguments at all. Check that with \ShowCommand\section.

@UlrikeFischer What a surprise! If often use \section{Foo} and \section[Foo]{Foooooooooooooooooooooo} ;) Does it mean I should try to get these arguments from \@startsection? But \AddToHook{cmd/@startsection/before}{\seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {#8} \seq_show:N \g_tmpa_seq} just says “The sequence \g_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):

{##8}.”


@DenisBitouzé \@startsection doesn't have 8 arguments, only 6. You want to hook into \@sect.

@Skillmon Ah, OK. But isn't the documentation of \@startsection in classes.pdf a bit misleading when it reads: “The macro \@startsection has 6 required arguments, optionally followed by a ∗, an optional argument and a required argument: [...]”?

Well, it does. Just not it directly, that's just how TeX macros with optional arguments get implemented. \@startsection uses \@ifstar and \@dblarg for its argument parsing and then calls either \@ssect or \@sect, and only those two have the user provided argument containing the title.

At the user level, \section is documented to have

a *-variant;
an optional argument;
a mandatory argument.

You might be tempted to assume that it is defined by something like
\NewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{...}

Well, no, sorry. The implementation of \section has been essentially the same for about 40 years and \section has no argument at all. If you ask latexdef -s section from a terminal, you get
% article.cls, line 302:
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}

(similar definitions are given in other classes). It's actually \@startsection that first copes with the *-variant and then with the possible optional argument:
% latex.ltx, line 15507:
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  <...omitted irrelevant code...>
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}

You can “normalize” the command:
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy{\latexsection}{\section}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\latexsection*{#3}}{\latexsection[#2]{#3}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {Foo}
  \seq_show:N \g_tmpa_seq
}
\AddToHookWithArguments{cmd/textbf/before}{
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_show:N \g_tmpa_seq
}
 \AddToHookWithArguments{cmd/section/before}{
   \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {#3} % #3 is the section title
   \seq_show:N \g_tmpa_seq
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\textbf{Bold face}

\end{document}

You'll get on the terminal
The sequence \g_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {Foo}.
<recently read> }

l.25 \section{A section}

?
The sequence \g_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {Foo}
>  {A section}.
<recently read> }

l.25 \section{A section}

?
The sequence \g_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {Foo}
>  {A section}
>  {Bold face}.
<recently read> }

l.27 \textbf{Bold face}

?


OK, my test command \section maybe wasn't the best choice but at least I've learned that we can't rely on the LaTeX2e: An unofficial reference manual (see in particular what is said about “Sectioning”). The question now is: should we rely only on the commands defined in source2e.pdf to play with \AddToHookWithArguments{cmd/...}? If so, this restriction should IMO be documented in lthooks-doc and/or ltcmdhooks-doc.
